# How can i use RRDtool to plot correlated data

Tags: rrdtool

For Example :
1. http response times correlated to CPU usage
2. http response times related to java script function response times

The objective is to establish a correlation between two variables and then see if one changes the other one follows in a deterministic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull as many data sources as you like (even from different rrd files) into a single graph ... use CDEF to adjust scaling ... you can also SHIFT data along the time axis for comparisons with past data.